# C++ multithreaded server with winsock and std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock

I have some problem with including `thread` module, when I add:

```
#include <thread>
```

the call to the bind function gives me error:

> Error 3   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,>' to 'int'    c:\users\ohadpeled\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\loginserver\loginserver\server.cpp 87  1   LoginServer
>       4   IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::_Bind" to "int" exists c:\Users\OhadPeled\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LoginServer\LoginServer\Server.cpp 87  20  LoginServer

I don't understand why it cause this error, without including the thread module the call works fine. I'd be happy if someone will explain me what cause it.

Here is part of the server class:

```
            /* Set TCP listening socket */
            ListenResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen); // Error in this line
            if (ListenResult != SOCKET_ERROR) 
            {
                freeaddrinfo(result);

                ListenResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
                if (ListenResult != SOCKET_ERROR) 
                {
                    /* Accepting clients */
                    while(true)
                    {
                        ClientSocket = new SOCKET();
                        ADDR = new SOCKADDR_IN();
                        ADDRSize = sizeof(*ADDR);
                        *ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr*)ADDR, &ADDRSize);
                        if (*ClientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) 
                        {
                            /* I want to thread the handler function over here! */
                            Handler(ClientSocket, ADDR);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm using win7, and set the socket with winsock.

Comment: You should use I/O Completion Ports instead if you need highest performance on Windows. If your server is intended for multi platform, use `boost::asio`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler is resolving the `bind` symbol to the C++ function [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) instead of the WinSock function [`bind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In order to fix this, you can do one of two things:

1. Remove all `using namespace std;` declarations in your source file; or
2. Use the scope resolution operator `::` to explicitly refer to the `bind` function in the global namespace:

   ```
   ListenResult = ::bind(...);
   ```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried some ugly stuff to make it work ... The funny part is that g++ isn't bothered at all but Visual Studio is...